# ListActivity vs ListView

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I'm learning android programming, and here is my doubt:
I can create a full screen ListView with the ListView object itself, or through a ListActivity.

Is there one that is preferable to the other, whether it be for efficiency reasons, code maintainability, or Android best-practices?

Comment: these are 2 different object, although related. ListActivity is an activity that contains helpers for having a listview (there is a default layout with a listview, some methods allow simpler access to list properties). The listview is a view representing a list. it can be included anywhere (except in a scrollview), including, but not only, in a listactivity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's fullscreen, it should probably be a ListActivity.

It's not always clear how to divide parts of an app into Activities, but one Activity per screen is pretty common.<sup>1</sup>  You likely shouldn't be showing a fullscreen ListView over other Views in a single Activity.

Note that ListActivity is just a convenience to save a bit of boilerplate code for a common Activity layout.  The layout and IDs are preset, so that you don't have to create them.  However, if you were designing an app that included a fullscreen list, but custom Activities (maybe everything subclasses a BaseActivity class that handles checking authorization), there's no harm in making your own Activity with a fullscreen ListView as its layout.  (In that case, I'd recommend looking at the features of ListActivity like the empty view as it's more complex than merely a single ListView.)

<sup>1. This is actually more complex nowadays because Fragments are the norm and have even fuzzier boundaries, but we'll leave them out of this discussion.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

It depend on that activity function.

To display simple data or to use a listview as a picker then ListActivity is not a bad choice.

But, for more complex functions. rather than those you are forced to use listview inside an activity that contain other controls too.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion making a listView in xml is better.

in my application i have a listView and a tixtview in a framelayout , loading the listview data from database , if the database is empty i hide the listview and show the textView ( telling the user there is no data to show ) , and if there is data in the database i show the listview and hide the textview